# How do I create a pipe to connect two child processes using fork, pipe, and dup?

Tags: c, process, pipe, unix

Let's say within a program I want to execute two processes, one to execute a `ls -al` command, then piping the result into the `wc` command, and displaying the output on the terminal. How can I do this using pipe file descriptors? So far the code I have written:

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int pipefd[2];
    int pipefd2[2];

    pipe(pipefd2);
    if ((fork()) == 0) {
       dup2(pipefd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
       close(pipefd2[0]);
       close(pipefd2[1]);
       execl("ls", "ls", "-al", NULL);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    if ((fork()) == 0){
        dup2(pipefd2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipefd2[0]);
        close(pipefd2[1]);
        execl("/usr/bin/wc", "wc", NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);
    close(pipefd2[0]);
    close(pipefd2[1]);
}
```

An example would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 12):

Your example code was syntactically and semantically broken (e.g. pipefd2 not decared, confusion between pipefd and pipefd2, etc.) Since this smells like homework, please make sure you understand my annotations below and ask more if you need to. I've omitted error checks on pipe, fork and dup, but they should be there, ideally.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t ls_pid, wc_pid;

    pipe(pipefd);

    // this child is generating output to the pipe
    //
    if ((ls_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        // attach stdout to the left side of pipe
        // and inherit stdin and stdout from parent
        dup2(pipefd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[0]);              // not using the right side

        execl("/bin/ls", "ls","-al", NULL);
        perror("exec ls failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } 

    // this child is consuming input from the pipe
    //
    if ((wc_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        // attach stdin to the right side of pipe
        // and inherit stdout and stderr from parent
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);

        close(pipefd[1]);              // not using the left side
        execl("/usr/bin/wc", "wc", NULL);
        perror("exec wc failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // explicitly not waiting for ls_pid here
    // wc_pid isn't even my child, it belongs to ls_pid

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It is **not** true that closing one `dup`'d file descriptor closes the other.  Closing one just removes one handle to the open file.  The file itself is not closed until all `dup`'d file descriptors to it are closed.

Comment: Oh, and you *should* close the `pipefd` file descriptors in the parent - it doesn't need them (and the reading child won't see end-of-file until the parent closes its handle on the writing end).  Again, `close()` only gets rid of the handle you pass it, the underlying pipe isn't closed until *all* of the handles to it, in *every* process, are closed.

Comment: Is your last comment correct? Aren't they both children of one parent?

Comment: can we get rid of `close` here?

Comment: @象嘉道 No, we cannot. In fact, we need more `close` as @caf pointed out. In the ls process, we can close both `pipedf[0]` (the process doesn't use it) and `pipefd[1]` (we already made a copy of it with `dup2`). In the `wc` process, we can close both `pipedf[0]` (the process already made a copy of it with `dup2`) and `pipefd[1]` (the process doesn't use it). Finally, the parent process should close  `pipefd[0]` and `pipefd[1]` as well because 1) it's not using them and 2) it cannot keep them open since the children would block. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77517347/10824322).

Answer (score 0):

### Code

I've commented out the code as thoroughly as possible. I've also added some minor error handling for handling process forking and command execution. As [@msw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282912/msw) pointed out, you only need a single pipe to communicate unidirectionally between two processes.

```c
// ls-wc-pipe.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t ls_pid, wc_pid;

    pipe(pipefd);

    // CHILD PROCESS: ls
    if ((ls_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        // We close-and-then-connect STDOUT to the pipe's write end so the process
        // write to the pipe instead of the screen/terminal.
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        // Since STDOUT_FILENO also refers to the pipe's write end, we can
        // close this file descriptor; it's no longer needed.
        close(pipefd[1]);

        // This process doesn't read from the pipe's read end so this is unused
        // and we should close it.
        close(pipefd[0]);

        // Execute the `ls` command, and exit if errors out.
        if ((execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-al", (char *) NULL)) < 0) exit(0);
    }
    else if (ls_pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork ls process");
        exit(0);
    }

    // CHILD PROCESS: wc
    if ((wc_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        // We close-and-then-connect STDIN to the pipe's read end so the process
        // read from the pipe instead of from the keyboard.
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);

        // Since STDIN_FILENO also refers to the pipe's read, we can
        // close this file descriptor; it's no longer needed.
        close(pipefd[0]);

        // This process doesn't write to the pipe's write end so this is unused
        // and we should close it.
        close(pipefd[1]);

        // Execute the `wc` command, and exit if errors out.
        if ((execl("/usr/bin/wc", "wc", (char *) NULL)) < 0) exit(0);
    }
    else if (wc_pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to fork wc process");
        exit(0);
    }
    
    // PARENT PROCESS

    // The parent process isn't using the pipe, however these descriptors are
    // another references to the pipe's read and write ends and we must close
    // them. Otherwise, it doesn't send the EOF so the children can continue
    // (children block until all input has been processed).
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);

    // The parent process waits for both children to finish before exiting.
    int ls_status, wc_status;
    pid_t ls_wpid = waitpid(ls_pid, &ls_status, 0);
    pid_t wc_wpid = waitpid(wc_pid, &wc_status, 0);

    // Return main's status based on whether the parent process waited both
    // child processes successfully. Status based only on `ls_status`.
    return
        ls_pid == ls_wpid && WIFEXITED(ls_status) &&
        wc_pid == wc_wpid && WIFEXITED(wc_status)
        ? WEXITSTATUS(ls_status)
        : -1;
}
```

Compiling and running it:

```
$ ls
a.out         error.log     ls-wc-pipes.c out.log       so-pipes.c
$ gcc ls-wc-pipe.c && ./aout
      8      65     449
```

Your result will vary depending on what you've in the directory that `ls-wc-pipe.c` runs.